# Checking if string contains numeric value, then display the value doubled

Tags: c#

user input:
"I have 3 apples"

output:
"I" 
"have"
"6" 
"apples"

My C#:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a string...");
            string delimeter = " ";
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] output = input.Split(Convert.ToChar(delimeter));

            foreach (var substring in output)
            {               
                Console.WriteLine(substring);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

I need help getting on the right track. My code only breaks the sentence apart using space as a delimiter.

Comment: Well how do you know what format the input string will be in?  What if they type "I have six apples"?  Are we talking artificial intelligence here?  What if they type "I am 23 years old and I have 6 apples"?  What number should it double?

Comment: can you try System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex.Replace(input,"\d+", match=> match => (int.Parse(match.Value)*2).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

Comment: @rory.ap in that case the output would look like:" I am 46 years old and I have 12 apples"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try

```
foreach (var substring in output)
{               
    int value;
    if(int.TryParse(substring, out value)){
        value = value * 2;
        input = input.Replace(substring, value.ToString());
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

You first need to check if your spitted string is a number, if it is then multiple by 2 and replace it in your input variable to get the expected output.

Comment: I'm very new to c# so i would not know how to check it. Are there any tutorials that can help? Thanks.

Comment: @julian The above solution in my answer should do that. int.TryParse checks if the string can be parsed to the number.

Comment: Oops my bad. I will just need to figure out how to display the string in parts (using the space delimiter). Thanks :)

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if it helped. Thank you :)

Comment: @julian - you should be able to use the Split function on a string to separate on spaces....

Answer (score 1):

Can you try followoing?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a string...");
        string delimeter = " ";
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        var result =  System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex.Replace(input,"\d+", match=>(int.Parse(match.Value)*2).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCul‌​ture));
        Console.WriteLine(result); 
         Console.Read();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm for example.

```
// an extension method to check if a string is all decimal digits
public static class StringHelper {
    public static bool IsNumeric(this string str)
    {
        if (str.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) return false;
        return str.All(char.IsNumber);
    }
}

...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string...");
    string delimeter = " ";
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] output = input.Split(Convert.ToChar(delimeter));

    foreach (var substring in output)
    {               
        if (substring.IsNumeric())
        {
            substring = (int.Parse(substring) * 2).ToString();
        }
        Console.Write(substring);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Read();
}
```

Please note that the code is only checking if a substring contains only decimal digits. It's not prepared to handle any number with decimal point for example, and it's also not completely safe. The code is not tested, and is ment only for example purposes.

I intentionally showed a code without using Regular Expressions, but if you're interested, check out the other answers for that alternative.

Comment: You can replace `str.IsNullOrEmpty() || str.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` with just `str.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` because it also checks for "Empty". [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I was copying it from one of my old helpers :)